# Cannot resolve symbol for class in another module

Tags: intellij-idea, testng

In my test file when I create an instance of a class from another module, it allows me to auto-import and auto-complete that class like I expect. But after I do that, when I add my first parentheses it says that it *Cannot find the deescalation to go to*. When I hover my mouse over the class it simply says that it *cannot revolve symbol*.

In the Project Structure I have a dependency on the other module as well as a dependency on the src folder for that module. Also, this project is using a library that uses testng so the method has a @Test annotation if that matters.

I have tried to invalidate my caches and restart, but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the file structure perhaps you are using.

```
└───maven-project 
    └───src
    ├───main
    │   ├───java
    │   ├───resources
    ├───test
    │   ├───java
    │___├───resources
```

If the class is in the test folder of the other module, it can not be seen in other modules. You need to move that class in the main folder of the other module to see it in your test module.

Files in the test folder are invisible to files in the main folder, or in modules that declare dependency of the module.

Comment: All my classes are in the main folder, but one module won't reference another.

Comment: You need to import the module as dependency in the module you want to use the classes, or in the parent POM, if you have one. Beware of cyclic dependencies, Maven doesn't like them.
https://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html